# How can I (unit) test a class behavior based on a static method call?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, static-methods, php-7

I have these 2 classes :

**AbstractTaskDispatcher**

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace MyExample;

abstract class AbstractTaskDispatcher
{
    public final function getResult(Task $task) : Result
    {
        if($worker = $this->getWorker($task))
            return $worker->getResult();
        else
            return Result::getUnprocessableTaskResult();
    }

    abstract protected function getWorker(Task $task) : Worker;
}

?>
```

**Result**

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace MyExample;

class Result
{
    private $code;

    public function __construct(int $code = 0)
    {
        $this->code = $code;
    }

    public static function getUnprocessableTaskResult() : Result
    {
        return new Result(1000);
    }

    public function getCode() : int
    {
        return $this->code;
    }
}

?>
```

I want to write a unit test with PHPUnit to get sure that AbstractTaskDispatcher::getResult() returns Result::getUnprocessableTaskResult() if no suitable Worker is found to process the Task.

I dont want to do this :

1. Arrange : $expectedResult = Result::getUnprocessableTaskResult();
2. Act : $result = $dispatcherStub->getResult(New Task());
3. Assert : assertEquals($result, $expectedResult);

Because it relies on Result class implementation and would not be a unit test.

I tried to do something :

```
<?php

    use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
    use MyExample as ex;

    class AbstractDispatcherTest extends TestCase
    {
        public function test_getResultSouldReturnUnprocessableTaskResultIfNoWorkerFound()
        {
            $dispatcher = $this->getMockForAbstractClass(ex\AbstractDispatcher::class);
            $arbitraryCode = 6666;
            $expectedResult = new ex\Result($arbitraryCode);
            $resultClass = $this->getMockClass('Result', ['getUnprocessableTaskResult']);
            $resultClass::staticExpects($this->any())
                ->method('getUnprocessableTaskResult')
                ->will($this->returnValue($expectedResult));

            $result = $dispatcher->getResult(new ex\Task([]));

            $this->assertEquals($expectedResult, $result);
        }
    }

?>
```

But staticExpects() method was deprecated and no longer exists in current PHPUnit version.

How can I write this test ?

Comment: Hi @berty, only one question: how can return `false` the method `getWorker`? The strict type definition can't accept you return something different to a `Worker` object instance

Comment: From a design point of view, why are you choosing to use a static method for that return? There's no reason the `AbstractTaskDispatcher` can't just return a new `Result` instance itself, given it knows about the Result class to begin with anyway.

Comment: Hi @Matteo, I wrote it with PHP 7.1 and nullable return types in mind, even if I'm on PHP 7.0 at the moment

Comment: @JohnJoseph, I didn't want to "hard-code" the content of this specific Result (code = 1000 in my example) as many times I use it in different classes/methods.

Comment: @JohnJoseph this practice is called "named constructor pattern"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply test as follow:

```
public function test_getResultSouldReturnUnprocessableTaskResultIfNoWorkerFound()
{
    $dispatcher = $this->getMockForAbstractClass(ex\AbstractTaskDispatcher::class);
    $dispatcher->expects($this->once())
        ->method('getWorker')
        ->willReturn(false);

    $result = $dispatcher->getResult(new ex\Task([]));

    // Unuseful: this is implicit by the method signature
    $this->assertInstanceOf(ex\Result::class, $result);
    $this->assertEquals(1000, $result->getCode());
}
```

NB: I change the method definition of the classe `AbstractTaskDispatcher` as follow in order to return a `false` value:

```
/**
 * @param Task $task
 * @return Result|false The Result of the task or false if no suitable Worker is found to process the Task
 */
abstract protected function getWorker(Task $task);
```

EDIT:

As You commented, you can't check as follow instead of hardcode the result code:

```
    $this->assertEquals(ex\Result::getUnprocessableTaskResult(), $result);
    // Or
    $this->assertEquals(ex\Result::getUnprocessableTaskResult()->getCode(), $result->getCode());
```

Hope this help

Comment: This is what I didn't want to do because this relies on Result class, which is outside the scope of the test. I can make this test fail or success by changing Result class code. For example, even if AbstractDispatcher::getResult() was broken, I could pass the test by returning 1000 in hard code in Result::getCode(). So this would not be strictly a *unit* test. Otherwise, if I'd choose to accept the "non-unity" of the test, I think I'd better `assertEquals(ex\Result::getUnprocessableTaskResult(), $result)` in the test to avoid writing "1000".